# Inserting comment to database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I know this has been mentioned many times in this thread but I still couldn't figure out how to solve my problem. I'm having difficulty on how to send and fetch my data from the comment.php to the insert.php

Here is my code for my comment.php:

(Notice the comments in javascript the method part [there's three of them], I've tried experimenting with them so that I could insert my data to the database but to no avail they didn't work. I'm still learning after all).Could someone help me. I'm still a beginner so I might find it difficult to understand an advance but i'll do my best.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ajax Comment</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min" />


<script type = "text/javascript" >
<!-- method 1-->
//$(document).ready( function() {
//  $('#submit').click( function() {
//  
//      $('#getResponse').html('<img src="bootstrap/images    /loading.gif">');
//      $.post( 'insert.php', function(sendRequest) {
//      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
//  (
//      if(xmlhttp.onreadystatechange == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
//      (
//          document.getElementbyId("getResponse").innerHTML =     xmlhttp.responseText;
//      )
//  )
//       xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?name="+document.getElementbyId("name").value+"    &email="+document.getElementbyId("email").value+"&web="+document.getElementbyId("url").value+"&    comment="+document.getElementbyId("body").value+,true);
//  xmlhttp.send();
//              $('#getResponse').html(sendRequest);

//      });
//  });


//});

<!-- -->

<!-- method 2-->

//function sendRequest() (
//  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
//  (
//      if(xmlhttp.onreadystatechange == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
//      (
//          document.getElementbyId("getResponse").innerHTML =     xmlhttp.responseText;
//      )
//  )
//          xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?name="+document.getElementbyId("name").value+"    &email="+document.getElementbyId("email").value+"&    web="+document.getElementbyId("url").value+"&    comment="+document.getElementbyId("body").value+,true);
//  xmlhttp.send();
//)

<!-- -->


<!-- method 3-->

// function sendRequest()
//{
//  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//      xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?name="+document.getElementbyId("name").value+"    &email="+document.getElementbyId("email").value+"&    web="+document.getElementbyId("url").value+"&        comment="+document.getElementbyId("body").value+,false);
//  xmlhttp.send(null);

//  document.getElementbyId("getResponse").innerHTML =     xmlhttp.responseText;
//}

<!-- -->
</script>

</head>

<body>



<form method = "post" action="">

<div id="main">





<div class="comment" style="display: block;">
            <div class="avatar">

                <img src="img/default_avatar.gif">

            </div>

            <div class="name">Avatar</div>
            <div class="date" title="Added at 02:24 on 20 Feb 2015">20     Feb 2015</div>
            <p>Avatar</p>
</div>

                <div id="addCommentContainer">
                <p>Add a Comment</p>

    <form id="addCommentForm" method="Get" action="">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

            <label for="url">Website (not required)</label>
            <input type="text" name="url" id="url">

            <label for="body">Comment Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5">    </textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id = "getResponse"></div>
</div>


</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code for the insert.php my php file where I perform the insertion of data to my database.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("comment");

   $name = $_GET['name'];
   $email = $_GET['email'];
   $web = $_GET['web'];
   $comment = $_GET['comment'];

   mysql_query("INSERT INTO demo (c_name,c_email,c_web,c_comment) VALUES     ('$name','$email','$web','$comment')");

   echo "Inserted Successfully";

   ?>
```

Comment: I know it's a demo, but as a side comment, and as you are still learning, **check SQL injection and how to prevent it**. With the current code, someone could set a comment like `"'); DROP DATABASE comment; --"` and delete your whole database. Move away from `mysql_` functions, use `mysqli_` or `PDO` and parameterized queries

Comment: thanks for the tip but which one are you referring from the drop database comment? is it inside the comment.php or the insert,php or both?

Comment: At least in insert.php: when you do the `mysql_query`, you pass values to the database without sanitizing them or anything. It's a recipe for disaster. You should move to `mysqli_` or `PDO` because it's safer (and I'd say almost easier), and also because `mysql_` is officially deprecated as of PHP5.5

Answer (score 0):

In your comment.php file , use Button,not submit.

And on click event of that button , call jQuery ajax

```
$('#button_id').click(function(){
   //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
   var params,name,email,url,body;
   name=$("#name").val();
   email=$("#email").val();
   url=$("#url").val();
   body=$("#body").val(); 

   params = {'name':name,'email':email,'web':url,'comment':body};

   $.ajax({
   url:'insert.php',  
   data:params,
   success:function(){
     alert("hello , your comment is added successfully , now play soccer :) !!");
   }
   });
});
```

**Update**

I dont know whether you used button or submit. So I am specifying for you.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="button_id" value="Submit" >
```

Comment: Tell me where is your HTML Form for comment ? In comment.php"?

Comment: tnx for the code i tried but something's wrong with my insert.php, I'm getting this error:

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: web in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: comment in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 9
Inserted Successfully

Comment: when i press the submit button for the comment nothing happens so i tried going to the insert.php and I suddenly got that error. I look at the database and the only thing that got inserted is the c_id which is my primary key and nothing else.

Comment: @DavidDiaz LOL , you are very talented :) Add my code in <script> tag in your comment.php

Comment: i'm afraid i think i'm experiencing another technical problem with my xampp.,i'm pretty sure the syntax code for my insert.php is correct yet i received an undefined index error.,

Comment: i already did it's just that my insert,php is having an error., like this one: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 6. Anyway thanks for the help I'm pretty sure your code is right so I'll just notify you after I have fix the other error., I think it has something to do with my xampp not performing well.

Comment: @DavidDiaz ask me , its your PHP code with error !! :) Are you really smarter than me?

Comment: sorry for the late reply i'm not saying that i'm smarter than you. To clarify things, I've created a simple create.php file with the right syntax and a correct database and it seems that I've received an error like this one for example "Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 6". Do you have any idea what causes this to occur?

Comment: paste your code from Simple.php Here , by editing the question

Comment: <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    mysql_select_db("comment");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    (
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO demo (c_name,c_email) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')");
    echo "Inserted !!!";
    )
    ?>
    <form method = "post" action = "">
    <div>
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <label for="email">Your Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </form>

Comment: I've received an error like this. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\create.php on line 8. Sorry for the typos since I don't know how to insert  a code into the comment. Anyways isn't the code in simple.php clear? Yet why do I receive this error.

Comment: I created it in a new thread. Check it out since it's too embarrassing for me to post codes in comments. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' " <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883628/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected>

Comment: the php problem has been solved. I'll try your codes next time since it's late now. Thanks for the help btw

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the form serialize function, its good approach.

```
$('#addCommentForm').submit(function(form){ 
   $.ajax({
      url:'insert.php',  
      data: $(form).serialize(),
      success:function(){
          alert("hello , your comment is added successfully , now play soccer :) !!");
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: tnx for the code i tried that but something's wrong with my insert.php, I'm getting this error: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 6 Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 7 Notice: Undefined index: web in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 8 Notice: Undefined index: comment in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment\insert.php on line 9 Inserted Successfully

Comment: when i press the submit button for the comment nothing happens so i tried going to the insert.php and I suddenly got that error. I look at the database and the only thing that got inserted is the c_id which is my primary key and nothing else

Comment: Ok I have did small change in code. Please try the above code now I hope  you will get the values in your insert.php page and from this page it will insert into database.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use this to submit the record to insert.php action in the form should be action = "insert.php"

```js
$('form#addCommentForm').on('submit', function(){
  $("#response").show();
 var that = $(this),
 url = that.attr('action'),
 type = that.attr('method'),
 data = {};
 
 that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value ){
   $('#response').html('<img src="images/loadingbar.gif"> loading...');
      var that = $(this),
   name = that.attr('name'),
   value = that.val();
  data[name] = value;
  
 }); 
 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: type,
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
   console.log(response);
   $(".ajax")[0].reset();
   $("#response").hide();
  }
 });
 return false; 
});
```

> form the db connection script use this

```js
<?php 
 $connect_error = 'sorry we\'re experiencing connection problems';
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die($connect_error) ;
 mysql_select_db('comment') or die($connect_error);
?>
```