# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ;

Tags: php

I'm sorry if this has been mentioned many times in the thread but I just want to ko some answer. Can someone tell me how I got an error like this

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\create.php on line 8

Here is my code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("comment");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    (
        $Name = $_POST['name'];
        $Email = $_POST['email'];


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO demo (c_name,c_email) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')");

        echo "Inserted !!!";
    )
?>
<form method = "post" action = "">
    <div>
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

            <label for="submit">Submit</label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">

    </div>


</form>
```

I'm pretty sure the php codes are correct so I ended up in confusion.

P.S. I've acknowledged that mysql_function are outdated now but I don't have the luxury to study for PDO or mysqli_ this semestral end term. Thanks

Comment: You're using `()` brackets instead of braces `{}` in your conditional statement.

Comment: @fred ah thanks my bad. I've overlooked such simple problems anyway thanks at first I thought it was a technical problem and got me frustrated. Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

`if` clauses in PHP have to be surrounden with *curly* brackets:

`if(statement) { /* your code goes here */ }`

Your code works this way:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $Name = $_POST['name'];
        $Email = $_POST['email'];


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO demo (c_name,c_email) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')");

        echo "Inserted !!!";
}
```

BTW [OT]: beware of SQL injections.

Comment: my bad. I've overlooked such simple problems anyway thanks at first I thought it was a technical problem and got me frustrated. Anyway thanks.

Comment: anyway it's fine since I'm still learning as a student so I'll keep that in mind about the sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why people don't use any IDE like phpStorm or NetBeans

If you were using an IDE you should see something like this and never post this question:

[image]

You can guess something is wrong with `(`

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("comment");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO demo (c_name,c_email) VALUES ('$Name','$Email')");

    echo "Inserted !!!";
}
?>
<form method = "post" action = "">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

        <label for="email">Your Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

        <label for="submit">Submit</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">

    </div>


</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. I wasn't told about this by my professor and oh this seems more readable. By the way the image you posted, is it phpStorm or Netbeans, the background is nice and is readable.

Comment: This is Phpstorm. If you have and `.edu` email you can have it for free. In fact, you can have any JetBrains product for free :) This is `Darcula` Theme. One of the themes that come with it :)

Comment: I don't have any .edu email, and I just checked out its website, they're not providing it for free except from the one you mentioned ( i think) so i'll just choose netbeans since it supports more languages anyway thanks for the tip.

Comment: phpStorm is only for html/js/xml/php . They have, IntelliJ IDEA that supports multiple languages too. I used phpStorm and NetBeans for about 2 years each product and I stay with phpStorm. You can download an EAP (Early Access Program) version of IntelliJ or phpStorm for free . IntelliJ IDEA EAP: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/EAP And phpStorm EAP: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program